# Errors with mini toc in scrbook

Tags: itemize, thesis, minitoc

This may look like a very silly question, but I honestly have no idea what stupid mistake I have in my files.

I am using this [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/dep-automatic-control-and-systems-engineering-university-of-sheffield-uk/frjyqdxrxghk). The template is filled in with lipsum text, and it does not show any problems after compiling.

Document class: scrbook

The template prints a partial TOC in each chapter:

[image]

But when I filled the file with the text needed,The same tex file raises some problems:

[image]

For chapter 2:

[image]

It looks like each time the mini toc is printed, it prints all the contents, but also, the firts line and the last one are wrong formated.

The minitoc is printed with this code:

```
---------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\printmyminitoc}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=20pt](s) {%
            \begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}{%
                \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\selectfont
                \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
                    }%
            \end{minipage}
            };%
            \draw[maincolor, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}] (s.north west) rectangle (s.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace*{3ex}
    \vfill
    \pagebreak
    }
```

And call in each chapter as:

```
\chapter{Introduction} % Main chapter title
\label{Ch1} % For referencing the chapter elsewhere, use \ref{Ch1} 
\cleanchapterquote{There is no wealth but life. Life, including all its powers of love, of joy, and of admiration.}{John Ruskin}

\startcontents[chapters]

\printmyminitoc{}
...
```

The error it gives is:

LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

[image]

Completely honest I have no idea what is going wrong. Since the template works fine with the lipsum text, and the only different thing I did was to fill the template with the needed text.

Any idea?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said at the beginning, it is a very silly mistake:

It happens that `\usepackage{titletoc}` has to be loaded before `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: Yes, it's generally a good idea to load \usepackage{hyperref} as late as possible …